Python unit testing: function patch does not get applied to consumer that runs in a separate thread
I am trying to test a consumer that consumes messages of a queue and creates the corresponding object in salesforce.
To test the consumer I have to start it in a new thread because, it is an infinite loop and otherwise my test would not continue after starting the consumer.
test_consumer.py
class TestRabbitMQ(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('src.consumer.add_service_id')
    @patch('src.xml_parser.get_service_id')
    def test_rabbitmq_messages(self, add_service_id_mock, get_service_id_mock):
        with RabbitMqContainer("rabbitmq:3-management", None, secrets.RABBITMQ_USER, secrets.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD) as rabbitmq:
            get_service_id_mock.return_value = {
                "crm": "1234"
            }
            add_service_id_mock.return_value = {
                "success": True,
                "message": "Service ID successfully added."
            }

            channel: BlockingChannel = configure_rabbitMQ(rabbitmq)

            consumer_thread = threading.Thread(target=consumer.main)
            consumer_thread.daemon = True
            consumer_thread.start()

            time.sleep(5)

            with open('tests/resources/dummy_user.xml', 'r') as file:
                test_message = file.read()

            channel.basic_publish(exchange='amq.topic', routing_key='user.frontend', body=test_message)
            channel.basic_consume(queue='crm', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=False)

            self.assertTrue(channel._consumer_infos)  # If consumer_infos is not empty, message was received

            consumer_thread.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()

consumer.py
def main():
    TEAM = 'crm'

    # Connect to RabbitMQ
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(secrets.RABBITMQ_USER, secrets.RABBITMQ_PASSWORD)
    try:
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host=secrets.HOST, port=secrets.PORT, credentials=credentials))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Failed to connect to RabbitMQ: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue=TEAM, durable=True)   

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    
        xml_string = body
        xml_string = xml_string.decode().strip()
    
        root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
        crud_operation = root.find('crud_operation').text
        logger.info(f"Received a {crud_operation} request for {root.tag}")
        logger.debug(f"Message: {xml_string}")
    
        try:
            variables = {}
            match root.tag, crud_operation:
                case 'user', 'create':
                    read_xml_user(variables, root)
                    payload = write_xml_user(**variables)
                    service_id = add_user(payload)
                    add_service_id(root.find('id').text, service_id, TEAM)
    
    
            ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
            logger.info(f'Processed {crud_operation} request for {root.tag}')
            log(logger, f"CONSUMER: {root.tag}.{crud_operation}", f"Processed {crud_operation} request for {root.tag}")
    
        except Exception as e:
            ch.basic_nack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag, requeue=False)
            logger.error(f'Failed to process {crud_operation} request for {root.tag}: {e}')
            log(logger, f"CONSUMER: {root.tag}.{crud_operation}", f"Failed to process {crud_operation} request for {root.tag}: {e}", error='true')


    channel.basic_consume(queue=TEAM, on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=False)
    logger.info("Waiting for messages to receive. To exit press CTRL+C")
    channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger = init_logger("__consumer__")
    try:
        authenticate()
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Failed to start consumer: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)

When I run the test, the code fails when it goes into:
read_xml_user(variables, root)

it logs an error stating:
2024-05-16 16:48:00:ERROR:__API__:Failed to process create request for user: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6000): Max retries exceeded with url: /getServiceId (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002383E3983B0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))

So it still tries to execute the get_service_id() which is called in xml_parser.py.
which confused me because I specifically patched this function in the test.
xml_parser.py
def read_xml_user(variables, root):
    for child in root:
        if child.tag == "routing_key" or child.tag == "crud_operation":
            continue
        elif child.tag == "address":
            for address_field in child:
                variables[address_field.tag] = address_field.text
        elif child.tag == "id" or child.tag == "company_id":
            if (child.text is not None):
                variables[child.tag] = get_service_id(child.text, TEAM)
            else:
                variables[child.tag] = None
        else:
            variables[child.tag] = child.text

My theory is that the consumer is being run in a new thread making it so the patches are not applied to the fucntions inside that thread.
As for my question: I can't figure out how to apply the patches to the consumer_thread.

You are correct about the problem. When you start consumer.main in the new thread, TestRabbitMQ.test_rabbitmq_messages is never called, so patches are never applied.  I'm not sure if there is a easy workaround.

I have fixed the issue by creating a function that first adds the patches to a function that starts the consumer and running this function in a thread. I also noticed the consumer thread would never exit so I added a "stay alive" loop.
def run_consumer():
  with patch('src.consumer.add_service_id', add_service_id_mock), \
        patch('src.xml_parser.get_service_id', get_service_id_mock), \
        patch('src.consumer.add_user', add_user_mock):
    start_time = time.time()
    while time.time() - start_time < 10:  # Run for 5 seconds
      try:
        consumer.main()
      except pika.exceptions.StreamLostError:
        break


consumer_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_consumer)
            consumer_thread.daemon = True
            consumer_thread.start()

